# Returning a file path in Django without the file extension

Tags: python, django, html5-video, multimedia

I'm creating a multimedia application on my Django site that allows users to upload photos, videos and audio - the files get encoded on a 3rd party service (mp4, ogg, webm and flv for videos), and then saved to the user's bucket on Amazon S3.  I'm specifically looking for an elegant solution to display the user's videos in HTML5 format.  Here's how my model looks:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = user_video_folder)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video_caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.video_title
```

Then the view:

```
def ViewAllVideos(request):
    videos = Video.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    template = 'site/media-videos.html'
    return render_to_response(template, {'videos': videos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template, I need to print the path for the multiple file formats that are generated during encoding, and was hoping to not have to add a column for *each* format in my model, so I was wondering if there was a way to return the file path WITH the file name, but without the extension, so it would like like so in the template:

```
<video width="900" height="506" preload="" controls="" autoplay="">
    <source src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ video.file }}.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
    <source src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ video.file }}.ogg" type="video/ogg;">
    <source src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ video.file }}.webm" type="video/webm;">
    <object width="900" height="506" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/foo/bar/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="/foo/bar/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param value="config={"clip": {"url": "{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ video.file }}.flv", "autoPlay":false, "autoBuffering":true}}" name="flashvars">
    </object>
</video>
```

Any help is appreciated! Cheers!

---

Here's my new view:

```
def ViewAllVideos(request):
    videos = Video.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    filenames = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(video.file))[0]
        for video in videos]
    context = {
        'videos': videos,
        'filenames': filenames,}
    template = 'site/media-videos.html'
    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add something like the below to your model, then use `{{video.file_minus_extension}}`

```
def file_minus_extension(self): 
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.url) 
    return basename
```

*EDIT: as per comment, just return filename*

```
def filename_minus_extension(self): 
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.file.name)) 
    return basename
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! The only issue I have with this is that it returns the full path to the image, but I need to specify a separate static URL..  Is it possible to ONLY return the file name?  So for example:

static.myurl.com/username/videos/foo.mp4

would return:

foo

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is something like:

```
os.path.splitext('file.ext')[0]  # Will return just 'file'
```

Note: This is supposed to be executed in your view and the returned value passed to your template.

For example, in your view you could do something like:

```
filenames = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(video.file))[0]
             for video in vides]
...
context = {'videos': videos,
           'filenames': filenames,
          }
return render_to_response(template, context, ...)
```

I think you're just using `video.file` in your template, so maybe you can even don't pass it to the template since it won't be needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment!  Like I mentioned, I'm new to Django, so forgive me if I don't understand correctly... So you say this should be in my view, so based on my original view, how would this look? Thanks again!

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an example. By the way, I've seen your comment about getting just the filename. That can be done using `os.path.basename`.

Comment: Thanks! So here's my new view:

def ViewAllVideos(request):
 videos = Video.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
 filenames = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(video.file))[0]
  for video in videos]
 context = {
  'videos': videos,
  'filenames': filenames,}
 template = 'site/media-videos.html'
 return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

...however I get the following error when hitting the page:

AttributeError at /site/media/videos/
'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yikes - didn't realize it wouldn't carry over line breaks... I'll add my new view above...

Comment: It seems it should be `video.file.name` since `video.file` is not really the path, but an object to access to the file.